# Making the controller clean and readable in (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have this rails controller which works fine but a lot of business logic is confined in the controller which I believe is not a good practice.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404


  def index
    year = params[:year].split('-') unless params[:year].nil?
    starting_year = year[0] unless year.nil? || year.empty?
    ending_year = year[year.length - 1] unless year.nil? || year.empty?
    genre = params[:genre][0] unless params[:genre].nil?
    language = params[:language][0] unless params[:language].nil?
    quality = params[:quality][0] unless params[:quality].nil?
    rating = params[:rating_bound][0] unless params[:rating_bound].nil?
    order_by = params[:orders_filter][0] unless params[:orders_filter].nil?
    @movies = Movie.search_title(params[:title]).search_language(language).search_on_starting_year(starting_year).search_on_ending_year(ending_year).search_video_quality(quality).search_genre(
      genre
    ).search_rating(rating).order_on_filter(order_by).includes(:profile_photo)
  end


  def show
    @movie = Movie.includes(
      :profile_photo, :created_by, movie_roles: [:actor], feedback: [:user] 
    ).left_outer_joins(:likes, :ratings).select(
      'movies.*, CAST(AVG(ratings.value) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS rating, count(likes.likeable_id) * 6 as total_likes'
    ).find params[:id]
    @reviews = @movie.feedback.select { |item| item.type == 'Review' }
    @comments = @movie.feedback.select { |item| item.type == 'Comment' }
    @directors = @movie.movie_roles.select { |role| role.role_played == 'director' }
    @actors = @movie.movie_roles.select { |role| role.role_played == 'actor' }
  end

 
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movie.build_profile_photo
  end


  def edit
  end

  def render_404
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", status: :not_found
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    parameters = movie_params
    @movie = Movie.new(parameters) 
    @movie.created_by = current_user

    if @movie.save
      redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new, notice: 'Not Saved!'
    end
 end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_movie
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def movie_params
    params.fetch(:movie, {}).permit(:name, :release_date, :video_quality, :synopsis, :genres, :language)
    params.fetch(:movie, {}).permit(:name, :release_date, :video_quality, :synopsis, :genres, :language, profile_photo_attributes: [:path])     
  end
end
```

I need to shrink the controller size and make the code look much clear and readable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there plenty different ways to do it, not sure how you are making these parameters, as they should not have [0] as I knew somewhere you doing differently. But any how. You can create simple Poro class and send your parameters to give you all records and then show to user. Currently there is a lot hype of Interactor and business logics, so I thought to give it a try. Here is what I have done.

```
bundle add interactor
```

Installed interactor which is used to create such logic you can read here [Interactor](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor). Then I created folder called `interactors` in the root of my project, note not in app but in root and added following line in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('interactors')
```

Now I changed action of controller like following

```
  def index
    @movies = SearchMoviesInteractor.call(params)
    if @movies.success?
      @movies
    else
      'No movies found'
    end
  end
```

and add one new class in my interactor folder called `interactors/search_movies_interactor.rb` yes search, well interactor are supposed to be each file for one operation like CRUD four files, now following is my interactor which is creating dynamically from private methods the condition field, I am not sure it is very clean but I love this as this way you can add as many filter as you want.

```
class SearchMoviesInteractor
  include Interactor

  def call
    filtering
  end

  def filtering
    if conditions.empty?
      Movies.all
    else
      'Movies.' << condition_clauses.join('.').to_s
    end
  end

  def conditions
    [conditions_clauses.join('.'), *conditions_options]
  end

  def conditions_clauses
    conditions_parts.map { |condition| condition.first }
  end

  def conditions_parts
    private_methods(false).grep(/_conditions/).map { |m| send(m) }.compact
  end

  def conditions_options
    conditions_parts.map { |condition| condition[1..-1] }.flatten
  end

  private

  def start_year_conditions
    year = conext.year.split('-') unless year.nil?
    "search_on_starting_year(#{context.year[0]})" unless year.nil? || year.empty?
  end

  def ending_year_conditions
    ending_year = context.year[context.year.length - 1] unless context.year.nil? || context.year.empty?
    "search_on_ending_year(#{ending_year})"
  end

  def title_conditions
    "search_on_starting_title(#{context.year})"
  end
end
```

Not I can see condition is being made correctly but I don't have database to check actual result so you have to check how does interactor return data, and then show it to user. those parts are just concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but adding 
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('interactors') , in the config/application.rb causes a NameError for me!

Comment: what is your version of rails? mine is 6 are you adding this inside config block? add after `  class Application < Rails::Application` line

Comment: Im also running rails 6, and I've added the config block as you've mentioned above, and it still gives me " NameError, uninitialized Constant" for my Search interactor!

Comment: oh sorry for that any how you can make simple class in `lib` folder or even in your `model` not recomended and then call it, it will work without adding, and no need to add Gem make simple Poro class and make your controller actions think.

Comment: Right! Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to simplify your controllers is use something like the scaffolding gem https://github.com/tubbo/controller_resources - that would reduce some of the boilerplate code.

For the `#index` method I would rewrite it chainging relations something like

```
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all.includes(:profile_photo)
    if params[:year].present?
      years = params[:year].split('-')
      @movies = @movies.search_on_ending_year(years.first)
      @movies = @movies.search_on_ending_year(years.last)
    end
    @movies = @movies.search_genre( params[:genre].first ) if params[:genre].present? 
    # etc
    @movies = @movies.order_on_filter(params[:orders_filter].filter) if params[:orders_filter].present?
  end
```

If you define your scopes something like
`scope search_on_ending_year, ->(year) { year ? some_condition : all }`
then you can also remove the conditionals above

Note that you can combine that a simple way to check both `nil?` and `empty?` in one step is to use `blank?`. Likewise `present?` is very universal and checks that values are not nil, strings are not blank, arrays are not empty, etc

In the `movie_params` method

```
  def movie_params
    params.fetch(:movie, {}).permit(:name, :release_date, :video_quality, :synopsis, :genres, :language)
    params.fetch(:movie, {}).permit(:name, :release_date, :video_quality, :synopsis, :genres, :language, profile_photo_attributes: [:path])     
  end
```

the first line is both redundant and ignored

I think your code would also be simpler if you structured your html to avoid array parameters like this `params[:orders_filter][0]`